# Problema de longitud al generar un alfanumerico C#

Tags: c#

estoy desarrollando un método estático en c#, que debe generar un codigo alfanumerico de acuerdo a la longitud ingresada por el usuario , el problema es que me está generando más digitos de los necesarios y no le encuentro el por que. Alguien podría darme una idea? dejo el codigo del metodo

```
 public static string AleatorioAlfanumerico(int longitud)
    {
        string password = "";

        char[] upperCase = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
        char[] lowerCase = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
        int[] numbers = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

        Random random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

        int k;

        int n;

        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        {
            n = random.Next(0, 3);

            if (n == 0)
            {
                k = random.Next(0, 25);
                password += upperCase;
            }

             if (n == 1)
            {
                k = random.Next(0, 25);
                password += lowerCase[k];
            }

             if (n == 2)
            {
                k = random.Next(0, 9);
                password += numbers[k];
            }


        }


        return password;
    }
```

y también dejo la clase program donde realizo el llamado :

```
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese cantidad de cupones a generar: ");
        int cantidad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la longitud de los codigos a generar: ");
        int longitud = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        List<string> lista = new List<string>();


        for (int j =0;j<cantidad;j++)
        {
            var aleatorio = Core.Security.Helper.AleatorioAlfanumerico(longitud);
            while (lista.Any(x => x == aleatorio))
            {
                aleatorio = Core.Security.Helper.AleatorioAlfanumerico(longitud);
            }
            lista.Add(aleatorio);
        }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ejemplos? seguiste tu codigo a ver en que paso se generan mas caracteres? a simple vista, no se ve nada malo...

Comment: Hola @AiluSch podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te dejo dos alternativas a lo que tienes hecho, quizás te interesen otras formas de resolver tu problema:

```
public static string AleatorioAlfanumerico(int longitud)
{
   Random rnd = new Random();
   string caracteres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
   string clave = "";

   for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
   {
      clave += caracteres[rnd.Next(62)];
   }

   return clave;
}
```

En este algoritmo se guardan todos los caracteres posibles en la **variable caracteres** de tipo **string**, posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo for** desde **0** hasta el parámetro de tipo **int llamado longitud**. Dentro de este **ciclo for** se van generando números aleatorios y concatenando a la **variable clave** cada caracter aleatorio generado devolviéndose finalmente una clave aleatoria.

El algoritmo descrito arriba no es del todo aleatorio, por lo que no es recomendado para generar claves seguras. Para esto debe usarse la **clase RNGCryptoServiceProvider** la cual si genera números aleatorios criptográficos en **C#**.

```
public static string AleatorioAlfanumerico(int longitud)
{
   using (var crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
   {
      var bits = (longitud * 6);
      var byte_size = ((bits + 7) / 8);
      var bytesarray = new byte[byte_size];

      crypto.GetBytes(bytesarray);
      Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(bytesarray));
   }
}
```

En este algoritmo se usa la **clase RNGCryptoServiceProvider** para generar una clave segura con caracteres alfanúmericos aleatorios. El **método GetBytes()** de esta clase  llena un **arreglo de bytes** con valores aleatorios  y el **método ToBase64String** convierte cada byte almacenado en el **arreglo de bytes** a su equivalente **string.**

**Referencia:** https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/csharp/generate-random-alphanumeric-strings-in-csharp/

Comment: Esto no responde a por qué falla el código del usuario que pregunta.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster mi respuesta es una alternativa a lo que tiene el op y cualquiera puede usarla en caso de que le haga falta, ademas es correcta y responde a la comunidad entera no a un usuario especifico

Comment: no he dicho que tu respuesta sea incorrecta, he dicho que no responde a lo que preguntó el usuario que creó el hilo. Por otro lado, tu respuesta resuelve una serie de problemas que no se sabe si este usuario (o cualquier otro) tiene; eso no hace que la respuesta sea mala, simplemente no se enfoca en lo que motivó la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos fallos en tu código:

1. Esto:

   ```
   int[] numbers = { ...}
   ```

   debería ser esto:

   ```
   char[] numbers = { ... }
   ```
2. Esto:

   ```
   if (n == 0)
   {
       k = random.Next(0, 25);
       password += upperCase;
   }
   ```

   debería ser esto:

   ```
   if (n == 0)
   {
       k = random.Next(0, 25);
       password += upperCase[k];
   }
   ```

El primer fallo provoca que cualquier número de una cifra se convirtiese en número de dos cifras:

| caracter | valor como `int` |
| --- | --- |
| '0' | 48 |
| '1' | 49 |
| '2' | 50 |
| '3' | 51 |
| '4' | 52 |
| '5' | 53 |
| '6' | 54 |
| '7' | 55 |
| '8' | 56 |
| '9' | 57 |

El segundo fallo provoca que se concatenen caracteres (en plural) no controlados en tu cadena.